# When does an enhanced for loop actually modify an Underlying Array?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

In an enhanced for loop like:

```
String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};

for (String s : a)
{
    out.println("String: " + s);
    s = in.readLine("New String? ");
}
```

When would this actually affect array A? We learned in class that an Enhanced For loops doesn't actually modify the underlying array but that there some special cases. I think this has something to do with memory management, but I'm not sure. Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When would this actually affect array A?

**Never**

Your not doing anything to `a` in any part of your code.

What you *might* have been taught is that you can **mutate the members of a container** (array or other).

To imagine what this means, suppose you have a train doing its route, and every car is an element in your array. You can't "mutate the train" (it will have the same cars in every station), but you can "mutate the cars" (people go on and off the cars in every stop).

Comment: I guess what I was trying to ask is that why would s = in.readLine("New String? "); not modify the corresponding item in A? Also would you mind explaining what you mean by "you can mutate the members of a container" a bit further?

Answer (score 3):

When you can modify the value without modifying the *reference*; for example, a `StringBuilder` is a *mutable* sequence of characters and you could do something like

```
StringBuilder[] a = { new StringBuilder("dog"), new StringBuilder("cat"),
        new StringBuilder("turtle") };

for (StringBuilder s : a) {
    out.println("String: " + s);
    s.setLength(0); // <-- clear the contents
    s.append(in.readLine("New String? ")); // <-- add the new content
}
```

Comment: That doesn't modify `a` at all. In fact, you could declare it `final` and get the same result.

Comment: I know, it modifies the values contained in the `StringBuilder`(s) that the array references. The [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) documentation specifies that *it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.* I am merely describing what is *possible* for OP.